# Form is not Submitted with Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, forms, jsp

I am working on a spring web application. In front end I am using `JSP.` I have a form (with id formToSubmit) in jsp -

```
<form:form id="formToSubmit" modelAttribute="jobForm" >
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><label>Your Comments:</label></td>
            <td>
                (Required if you do not review the samples)<br />
                <form:textarea id="newCommentsTextAreaId" path="newComments" rows="5" cols="50" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <br />
                <input onclick="apprvRqstSbmt()"type="image" src="/images/buttons/approveBtn.png" /><br />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <br />
                <input onclick="disApprvRqstSbmt()" type="image" src="/images/buttons/disApproveBtn.png" />
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

This form has two button - one for approve (with apprveBtn.png) and another for disapprove (with disApproveBtn.png). So I write some `javascript` to submit the form on button click -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function apprvRqstSbmt(){

        $("#formToSubmit").attr("action","/some/url/to/submit");
        $("#formToSubmit").submit();
    }

    function disApprvRqstSbmt(){
        $("#formToSubmit").attr("action","/some/url/to/submit");
        $("#formToSubmit").submit();
    }

</script>
```

When I click the disapprove button the form is submitted properly. But when I click on the approve button the form is not submitted properly. Can anyone help me why the form is not submitted properly?

Comment: Added an answer. Please let me know if it's working, or explain me what is the problem if I didn't understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `'method'` attribute in you `javascript`. You have to add `attr("method", "POST")` in your `javascript`. If I rewrite your code with my changes then it would be -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function apprvRqstSbmt(){
        $("#formToSubmit").attr("method","POST");               
        $("#formToSubmit").attr("action","/some/url/to/submit");
        $("#formToSubmit").submit();
    }
</script>
```

The disapprove button click working properly because the default method on form submit is 'GET'. Probably the disapprove button is throwing a get request.

Answer (score 2):

Just removed the `:form`, I can't see why is it necessary.

**Also, Thanks to Razib, except from the `:form` part which is unnecessary, you forgot to set the method to POST, so you can add it in the javascript part, or in the HTML. I did in both as you can see. You can use only one of them.**

```js
    function apprvRqstSbmt(){
        $("#formToSubmit").attr("method","POST");  //Razib solution
        $("#formToSubmit").attr("action","/some/url/to/submit");
        $("#formToSubmit").submit();
    }

    function disApprvRqstSbmt(){
        $("#formToSubmit").attr("method","POST");  //Razib solution
        $("#formToSubmit").attr("action","/some/url/to/submit");
        $("#formToSubmit").submit();
    }
```

```html
    <form id="formToSubmit" modelAttribute="jobForm" method="POST" >
        <table>
    
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label>Your Comments:</label></td>
                <td>
                    (Required if you do not review the samples)<br />
                    <form:textarea id="newCommentsTextAreaId" path="newComments" rows="5" cols="50" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <br />
                    <input onclick="apprvRqstSbmt()"type="image" src="/images/buttons/approveBtn.png" /><br />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <br />
                    <input onclick="disApprvRqstSbmt()" type="image" src="/images/buttons/disApproveBtn.png" />
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6fp1ukzL/